# Image class cant read target file

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

I am trying to read image deep in TEMP folder with Image.read method in order to convert it.

I've seen example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529524/image-magick-equivalent-to-convert-fill)

I've tried this

```
InitializeMagick("C:\\Users\\GrayMP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ImageMagick\\Images\\");
Image image;
image.read("result-0.bmp");
```

and this

```
InitializeMagick("");
Image image;
image.read("C:\\Users\\GrayMP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ImageMagick\\Images\\result-0.bmp");
```

, but I catch next exception.what():
    app.exe: unable to open image `↑Ё)': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/Op
enBlob/2674

Convertion via ImageMagic works fine, I can do all what I want, but, lib integration doesn't work.

I can't get what I am doing wrong

Comment: I think you need to expand the environment variable `TEMP using this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx

Comment: @MarkSetchell the TEMP is only here for shorter describe. I use full hardcoded path in my code. I have updated post with full paths. Thought posting full hardcoded paths will be strange.

Comment: Two ideas. 1. Convert your `bmp` to `jpg` at the commandline first and see if your code can read the `jpg`. 2. Move your image to the directory your program runs in.

Comment: 1.1: Init with full path, read(justName): no such file; 
1.2: Empty init - read(fullpath) - Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/Op
enBlob/2674 . 
2: placed file to app folder, empty init, read(justName) - Invalid argument.  
I have noticed that in first time when I run edited code - it throws invalid argument, second one is "no such file". In case 2 and 1.2.